# Generic Types ("List<? extends> " ) in HashMap's Value

Tags: java, generics

I did a generic type test.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

there are two methods:

```
private static void extendTest(List<? extends A> superList) {
    System.out.println("extendTest over.");
}

private static void extendMapTest(HashMap<String, List<? extends A>> superMap) {
    System.out.println("extendMapTest over.");

}
```

and I create a `list` and a `map`:

```
List<B> childList = new ArrayList<>();
childList.add(new B());
extendTest(childList); // TAG1: it is OK.

HashMap<String, List<B>> childMap = new HashMap<>();
childMap.put("hello", childList);
extendMapTest(childMap);  // TAG2: ERROR!
```

why TAG1 is OK, and TAG2 is error?
how can I correct TAG2?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 4):

`List<? extends A>` is not a super type of `List<B>`. See [the offical generics tutorial on upper bounding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html).

To fix, define childList like this:

```
List<A> childList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can still add a `B` to a `List<A>`, because a 
`B` is an `A`.

And define your map method like this:

```
private static void extendMapTest(HashMap<String, List<A>> superMap) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider.

You can create another class

```
class C extends A {}
```

and inside your `extendMapTest(HashMap<String, List<? extends A>> superMap)`

you are free to do:

```
List<C> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new C());
superMap.put("A", list);
```

but that is in contradiction with the declaration of the childMap object you're passing to extendMapTest

```
HashMap<String, List<B>> childMap
```

I guess the compilation error prevents this or similar situation

Answer (score 0):

it is as simple like `List<Integer>` are not subtype of `List<Number>`  even though Number and Integer are related and in the same way `AnyClass<A>` is not related with `AnyClass<B>` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) too

The simple option is simply define your map with wild card too , no code change required ,like

```
HashMap<String, List<? extends A>> childMap = new HashMap<>();
```

e.g with modified code to demonstration

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
    public int a=9;
}


private static void extendTest(List<? extends A> superList) {
        System.out.println("extendTest over.");
    }

    private static void extendMapTest(HashMap<String, List<? extends A>> superMap) {
        System.out.println("extendMapTest over."+((B)(superMap.get("hello").get(0))).a);

    }

        List<B> childList = new ArrayList<>();
        childList.add(new B());
        extendTest(childList); 

        HashMap<String, List<? extends A>> childMap = new HashMap<>();
        childMap.put("hello", childList);
        extendMapTest(childMap);
```

Output:

```
extendTest over.
extendMapTest over.9
```